# *AppName* does not have an architecture that iPhone 5 can execute

Tags: ios, xcode

We started getting these after upgrading Xcode to 7.2. Would anyone know anything about it?

Building Settings / Supported Platforms is set to "iOS"

Building Settings / Valid Architectures is set to "arm64"

[Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCUFu.png)

Comment: What os is iPhone5 running?

Comment: The iPhone5 doesn't use the arm64 architecture, you have to add the one it uses (armv7 I think)

Comment: All iPhones 5 had the issue, independent from the iOS version. Adding "armv7" to the Valid Architectures solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add armv7 as a valid architecture under Build Settings for all the targets.