# APPNAME does not have an architecture that iPad Retina can execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode7

My app (made for iPads only) will test run in all iPad sims except iPad Retina. Build succeeds and I get a dialog that says:

> APPNAME does not have an architecture that iPad Retina can execute

I found two other similar questions for [iPhone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918385/appname-does-not-have-an-architecture-that-iphone6-can-execute) and [iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298118/appname-does-not-have-an-architecture-that-iphone-5-can-execute) but neither answer resolves my issue.

In my `Build Settings` I have:

```
Architectures                 : Standard architectures (armv7,arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Base SDK                      : Latest iOS (iOS9.2)
Build Active Architecture Only: No
Supported Platforms           : iOS
Valid Architectures           : arm64 arm7 arm7s
```

What else is needed to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Please provide provide a link to your full build log (host it on dropbox or pastebin or something like that).  From your shown build settings, I'd expect your app to be built fat (i386 and x86_64) for the simulator, so it should work just fine in the iPad Retina sim.

Comment: This is just the command line outputs: http://pastebin.com/aF6EzFMt but if you need more/all of the log file, I can resubmit.

Comment: Yeah, I’d like to see the full log.  Also, look in /var/log/system.log for a line that looks like: "No architectures intersection between XXXXXX (XXXXX) and XXXXX (XXXXX)” at the time you hit this, and include that above.