# projectName does not have an architecture that deviceName can execute

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this dialog box pop up upon building the application:

> projectName does not have an architecture that deviceName can execute.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298118/appname-does-not-have-an-architecture-that-iphone-5-can-execute), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290077/projectname-does-not-have-an-architecture-that-iphone-5-can-execute), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918385/appname-does-not-have-an-architecture-that-iphone6-can-execute) already, but none of the answers there solve my problem. I'm trying to run my application on a 5th generation iPod Touch (released in September 2012) that's running iOS 9.3.1, and according to [this image](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51adfbd9e4b095d664d9b869/t/579b30e029687f6efd7530ce/1469788384687/MatrixV4b6.pdf),

> 32bit/Cortex A9/ARMv7-A

is the architecture that this device supports. My project's deployment target is 9.0.

[image]

What do I have to change under the "Architectures" or "Valid Architectures" setting to be able to run my application properly?

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: @Kymer 8.2 beta (8C30a)

Comment: `Valid Architectures` is bold, meaning it has been altered in some way. Could you try 'resetting' it to the default values? (highlight the line and hit backspace). It's also a good idea to [download](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) a non-beta version of Xcode.

Comment: @Kymer It works! Please post that as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Glad it worked! But I'd recommend downloading a non-beta version of  Xcode 8 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it looks like `Valid Architectures` is bold, meaning it has been altered in some way. Try 'resetting' it to the default values, by highlighting the line and hitting backspace. It's also a good idea to [download](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) a non-beta version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks very much for this one. very helpful